# Weird configuration file on desktop after Chrome Twitter Lite installation

Tags: google-chrome, configuration, twitter

I'm still kind of new to Linux, even though I've been using Ubuntu since 2018.

A config file appeared on my desktop (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04) right after (I guess) I installed Twitter Lite through Google Chrome (it kind of felt like installing an extension).

So, what is this file? Why is the name of the file so weird? It feels like a scam file. Is it safe to delete it? And why would it appear on my desktop?

```
chrome-panfkkhihbglmaommdcbgghogdofkjpi-Default.desktop
```

Thank you in advance.